# NSUserDefaults Custom object - Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I must be incorrectly using Custom Objects for NSUserDefaults. The error " Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')". Below is my code, the Goal class is of particular interest, since this is where I am adopting the NSCoding protocol.

This code is global.

```
func saveGoals (goals : [Goal]) {
    var updatedGoals = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(goals)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(updatedGoals, forKey: "Goals")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

func loadCustomObjectWithKey() -> [Goal] {
    if let encodedObject : NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Goals") as? NSData {
        var encodedObject : NSData? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Goals") as? NSData
        var goal : [Goal] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedObject!) as [Goal]
        return goal
    } else {
        return [Goal]()
    }
}
```

This code is in GoalsViewController.

```
class GoalsViewController: MainPageContentViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: GoalsTableView!

    var cell = GoalTableViewCell()

    var goalsArray : Array<Goal> = [] //

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        if var storedGoals: [Goal] = loadCustomObjectWithKey() as [Goal]? {
            goalsArray = storedGoals
        }
        //retrieve data.

        var goal = Goal(title: "Walk the Dog")
        goalsArray.append(goal)
        saveGoals(goalsArray)

        self.tableView?.reloadData()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        var notification = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

        notification.addObserver(self, selector: "finishCreatingGoal:", name: "FinishCreatingGoal", object: nil)
    }

func finishCreatingGoal(notification : NSNotification) {
        if (notification.name == "FinishCreatingGoal") {
            var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
            var text = userInfo["text"]! as String
            var index = userInfo["index"]! as Int

            var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)) as GoalTableViewCell
            goalsArray[index].title = cell.goalTextField.text
            saveGoalList(goalsArray)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

This code is in the Goal class.

```
import UIKit

class Goal : NSObject, NSCoding {

    var title : String? = ""
    var checkmarked : Bool? = false 
    var isLastCell : Bool? = false 
    var enabled : Bool? = true 

    var priority = Priority.defaultPriority

    override init() {
    }

    init(title : String) {
        self.title = title
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(title!, forKey: "title")
        aCoder.encodeBool(checkmarked!, forKey: "checkmarked")
        aCoder.encodeBool(isLastCell!, forKey: "isLastCell")
        aCoder.encodeBool(enabled!, forKey: "enabled")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        title = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as String!
        checkmarked = aDecoder.decodeBoolForKey("checkmarked") as Bool
        isLastCell = aDecoder.decodeBoolForKey("isLastCell") as Bool
        enabled = aDecoder.decodeBoolForKey("enabled") as Bool
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd guess that one of your Goal object's `title` is nil. Is this line: `goalsArray[index].title = cell.goalTextField.text` guaranteed to set it to a non-nil value?

Comment: yes, it is guaranteed non-nil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to just copy code from a working project I have:

here is the Game object class with data from a math flash card game:

```
import Foundation

class GameData: NSObject {

    var sign: String = "+"
    var level: Int = 1
    var problems: Int = 10
    var time: Int = 30
    var skipWrong: Bool = true
    var usedTime: Int = 0
    var correctCount: Int = 0
    var correctTopNumber: [Int] = [Int]()
    var correctBottomNumber: [Int] = [Int]()
    var wrongTopNumber: [Int] = [Int]()
    var wrongBottomNumber: [Int] = [Int]()
    var date: NSDate = NSDate()

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(sign, forKey: "sign")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(level, forKey: "level")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(problems, forKey: "problems")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(time, forKey: "time")
        aCoder.encodeBool(skipWrong, forKey: "skipWrong")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(usedTime, forKey: "usedTime")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(correctCount, forKey: "correctCount")
        aCoder.encodeObject(correctTopNumber, forKey: "correctTopNumber")
        aCoder.encodeObject(correctBottomNumber, forKey: "correctBottomNumber")
        aCoder.encodeObject(wrongTopNumber, forKey: "wrongTopNumber")
        aCoder.encodeObject(wrongBottomNumber, forKey: "wrongBottomNumber")
        aCoder.encodeObject(date, forKey: "date")
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        sign = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("sign") as String
        level = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("level")
        problems = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("problems")
        time = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("time")
        skipWrong = aDecoder.decodeBoolForKey("skipWrong")
        usedTime = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("usedTime")
        correctCount = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("correctCount")
        correctTopNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("correctTopNumber") as Array
        correctBottomNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("correctBottomNumber") as Array
        wrongTopNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("wrongTopNumber") as Array
        wrongBottomNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("wrongBottomNumber") as Array
        date = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("date") as NSDate
    }

    override init() {
    }
}
```

This part looks about the same as yours, but with more variable types.  The archiver and retriever classes differ from you:

```
import Foundation

class ArchiveGameData:NSObject {

    var documentDirectories:NSArray = []
    var documentDirectory:String = ""
    var path:String = ""

    func ArchiveResults(#dataSet: [GameData]) {
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("results3.archive")

        if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(dataSet, toFile: path) {
            //println("Success writing to file!")
        } else {
            println("Unable to write to file!")
        }
    }

    func RetrieveGameData() -> NSObject {
        var dataToRetrieve = [GameData]()
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("results3.archive")
        if let dataToRetrieve2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? [GameData] {
          dataToRetrieve = dataToRetrieve2
        }
        return(dataToRetrieve)
    }
}
```

Finally, the code for storing and retrieving from within a ViewController:

```
//retrieveing
    var gameDataArray = ArchiveGameData().RetrieveGameData() as [GameData]

//Archiving
      gameData = GameData() //create local object then append all the new data, then store it
gameData.sign = buttonStates.sign
        gameData.level = buttonStates.level
        gameData.problems = buttonStates.problems
        gameData.time = buttonStates.time
//etc. for all properties

      ArchiveGameData().ArchiveResults(dataSet: gameDataArray)
```

Comment: Steve, I think it would be a good idea to add the NSCoding protocol to your class declaration GameData