# Intended way to store a list of goals

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is the following code a suitable way to do this? It will have to work for a tableView, although I wanna make sure this is not a poor implementation of using the Realm.framework. I would access data the following way (as an example):

```
var goalList = Goals()
self.textField.text = goalList.goals[indexPath.row]
```

Goal.swift

```
import UIKit
import Realm

class Goal: RLMObject {

    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var checkmarked = false
    dynamic var disabled = false
    dynamic var isLastInList = false

}
```

Goals.swift

```
import UIKit
import Realm

class Goals: RLMObject {
    dynamic var goals = RLMArray(objectClassName: Goal.className())
}
```

Comment: are you married to Realm?  Would you like to use NSCoding?  I can post code for storing objects.

Comment: The last time I tried NSCoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174989/nsuserdefaults-custom-object-property-list-invalid-for-format-200-property-l?noredirect=1#comment41042033_26174989

Comment: I can't answer the Realm question, but I can fix your NSCoding example.  Should I bother?

Comment: I wrote the code yesterday so sure : ), you'll earn yourself a checkmark

Comment: Give a a few minutes

Comment: okay it is there.  Once you get it working once, you never need to pay attention to it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let goalList = Goal.allObjects() //This returns an array of goals
let goal = goalList[indexPath.row] // Returns a goal object
self.textField.text = goal.title
```

Answer (score 1):

Goal.swift is perfect. But you don't need Goals.swift.
If you take a look at the simple example provided in the download package that should show you pretty much what you need.